# Run south default data migrations for built-in applications such as auth.group or flatpages?

Tags: django, django-south, data-migration

The issue at hand is that in order to install default data into the database for built-in django applications such as **flatpages** or **auth.group** requires specifying **SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES** although the South documentation isn't very clear regarding the directory structure and the way to generate such data migrations.

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not necessary to use South for this, you can use an initial fixture which is auto loaded when you do a `syncdb`:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#automatically-loading-initial-data-fixtures

The docs do note that from Django 1.7 onwards this is deprecated (in fact `syncdb` itself is deprecated) and you should make a data migration using the new built-in migrations functionality, which supersedes South:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

If you want to use South migrations for say `django.contrib.auth.models.Group` then I think you can do it like this:

```
/projectroot/
/projectroot/myapp
/projectroot/myapp/migrations
/projectroot/myapp/migrations/__init__.py
/projectroot/myapp/migrations/auth/__init__.py
/projectroot/myapp/migrations/auth/0001_initial_groups.py  # arbitrary name
```

(any structure that results in a sane Python dotted import path to your actual migration from your project code)

Then in settings:

```
SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES = {
    'auth': 'myapp.migrations.auth',
}
```

Comment: Yes. That is why I want to use data migrations, I used initial_data.json before but...

Comment: If you're not on Django 1.7 then initial fixture is the right way to do it. If you are on 1.7 you shouldn't be using South and I assume there is no problem making data migrations for built in apps (since apps no longer have to be 'converted to South' to tell `syncdb` to ignore them).

Comment: Ok but how to avoid rewriting every time with the default data? I want to be able to edit it afterwards, that is also a reason for using data-migrations

Comment: I'd probably do that with a fixture and then load it manually (or as part of Fabric/Ansible etc deploy scripts)... have updated answer with what I think is needed for South though

Comment: But then, myapp does not have anything to do with auth.group except that it holds it's data migrations?

Comment: `SOUTH_MIGRATION_MODULES` is giving South a python import path where to find migrations for a given app_label... instead of the default location which would be a directory inside the app, which of course you can't make for 3rd party apps